# Heartbeat between two local applications

Tags: c#, wpf, ipc

I am currently working on a WatchDog application that will ensure a Player is always running. Both, the WatchDog and the Player are running on the same computer.

I implemented a simple `DispatcherTimer` to look over the process and check if the Player is running or not. If it is not, run it.

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("Player");  
if (processList.Length == 0)  
{  
     // Run Player
     return false;  
}  
else  
{  
     return true;  
}
```

However, I also want to implement a Heartbeat between those two applications. If the Player freezes, the WatchDog will kill it and start a new instance.

What would be the optional way to implementa that?

- Player to create an empty file on the drive and the WatchDog to delete it each X seconds. If the file is not there, the player probably froze.
- Use the WCF framework to create a connection between them
- Something else?

Comment: FYI: The general term for this is IPC or inter-process communication.